# Internet running slower on one PC in household after internet went down one night

Tags: internet, ethernet, internet-connection, gigabit-ethernet

Earlier this week internet went down for a few hours, likely due to a storm. After it came back up, found my PC frozen, which isn't common.

After restarting, internet speed seems to be slow but in a sporadic way. Sometimes things load well enough. Sometimes barely at all.

PC is using Windows 10 Home. I'm connected via a Cat8 ethernet cable so it's not a Wi-Fi issue. We pay for 1GB internet speed via Verizon FIOS.

Speedtest.net usually shows 800-900 down and 400-500 up with 15-20 ping; but now I'm seeing 300-400 down and 100-200 up with still 15-20 ping.

I've tried restarting modem/router to no avail and the weirdest thing about this is that it seems this only effects this PC. My and 3 other peoples' mobile devices run fine and as do 2 other PCs in the house. The only thing that seems to be having any issues is this PC and it only seems to be the internet.

I'm not entirely sure what to do or even attempt to do. All I know is the issue seems to be entirely on the side of my PC. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Internet going out is external to the computer.

That being the case, run TCP/IP Reset, Flush DNS and then fully restart.

I assume you are running Windows and the commands below work on at least Windows Vista forward. (Works also on earlier operating systems).

Open `cmd.exe` with “Run as Administrator.”

1. `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt`
2. `ipconfig /flushdns`

Now fully restart and test.

Another thing to try (Windows 8 and above) is DISM / SFC

1. Open `cmd.exe` with “Run as Administrator.”
2. `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup`
3. `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth`
4. `SFC /SCANNOW`
5. Restart when all the above is complete and test.

If this fails to resolve your issue try a different network card (USB network card).

Comment: Well, I've did this. It doesn't seem to have worked and I have a strange new issue. The speed related stuff appears to be the same but now some sites and programs just won't load. I can get on YouTube and search stuff on Google just fine, but other sites just don't load at all and programs like discord or steam won't load up at all.

Comment: Something else wrong with the computer that was not related to loss of internet?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. I have no issue running anything unless it involves internet. I'm also on my phone now because this site is one of the ones that won't load anymore.

Comment: When I try to load up one of the sites that won't load it says "<site>'s DNS address could bot be found. Diagnosing the problem"

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: I posted the steps in my answer

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll give that a try then

Comment: Well, I tried the 2 DISM things and the SFC scan and the same issue from after the dna flush is still happening.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do to with losing internet. Try a different network card.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 other PC Machines, without Issues.
I would temporarily move atleast 1 PC to the room with the broken machine, connect the same Ethernet cabling and check.

If the working PC shows Issues, the Ethernet Cabling (or something further down stream) is the culprit.
[[ **SOLUTION** : remove & replug the cabling till the router , If Issue Persists : recabling/rewiring ! ]]

If the working PC works without Issues, the broken PC is the culprit.

Get a common usb wifi dongle and check whether Internet works fine.
If YES, your Ethernet Port (hardware) has gone bad.
[[ **SOLUTION** : replace the Interface ! ]]

If NO, Windows itself has got corrupted. If you have Linux LiveCD, you can boot there and check  to confirm that it is Hardware Issue (Ethernet Port) or Software Issue (Windows OS or Driver Corruption). It may turn out that Windows is the culprit :
[[ **SOLUTION** : reinstall Windows ! ]]